# How to indent in GitHub wiki's editor?

Tags: github

I'm using chrome with macbook. When I attempt to use `tab` to indent code blocks in GitHub wiki's editor/textarea, I fail miserably because tab is meant for shifting focus between fields ... as it should be in a browser.

I tried the outdated advice from the web:

> In order to actually insert a tab you need to press the following key combination: ctrl + alt + tab. Note: depending on your keyboard, the alt key is sometimes called the option key.`

But it does *NOT* work.

On gitlab its easy to use `tab` because they have a full-screen mode in their wiki. But I'm stuck working on a GitHub repository's wiki.

So question(s):

a) How to indent a line in GitHub wiki's editor or textarea?

b) How to indent a a selected set of lines in GitHub wiki's editor or textarea?

Answer (score 2):

A simpler solution might be to use GitHub's [fenced code blocks](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-and-highlighting-code-blocks/#fenced-code-blocks), e.g.

````
```python
from foo import Foo

bar = Foo()
```
````

This has at least two benefits:

- You don't have to worry about indenting whole blocks of code; you can simply mark the beginning and end of the block
- You can optionally include a language hint (here I've used `python`) so GitHub can add syntax highlighting to your code block

Comment: I indent triple-ticked code blocks, have a look and you'll understand: https://github.com/pulkitsinghal/pulkitsinghal.github.io/wiki/DropWizard#getting-started

Did I misunderstand how you are suggesting I indent them? I think we are talking about 2 different things :)

Comment: Ah, you're indenting code so it's included in a list element. I'm not aware of any "nice" way of doing that to entire blocks on GitHub. Manually you can indent by four spaces instead of a tab.

Answer (score 1):

I used copied tabulation symbol and it works for image indent.
Or you can hold Alt and enter 0009 on Numpad and then release Alt - tabulation symbol will be printed to the selected place in wiki.

Answer (score 0):

for me its `option ⌥ + control ⌃ + tab`

not only for GitHub, but also StackOverflow and every other Website this problem occurs:)

ps.: I am using safari...